# Antlr4 Can't load as lexer or parser

Tags: antlr4

I know this probably looks like a duplicate. It's not. I've searched for an hour, trying everything I've seen and nothing has worked.

I have an antlr4 grammar file called `MathLang.g4`. I have put it into its own folder called `Grammartest`. `antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar` is in `C:\Program Files\Java\libs`, along with `antlr4.bat` and `grun.bat`. The folder is in the PATH and the jar is in the CLASSPATH. The bat files read as such:

```
// antlr4.bat
java org.antlr.v4.Tool %*

// grun.bat
java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig %*
```

I then run the following commands in the Grammartest folder:

```
antlr4 MathLang.g4
javac MathLang*.java
grun MathLang def
```

`antlr4` and `javac` run silently, generating the `.java` and then `.class` files. `grun` responds with `Can't load MathLang as lexer or parser`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently I had to add the folder that I was testing in (Grammartest) to the CLASSPATH.